# How to open list of urls one by one in firefox

Tags: mac, firefox, url

I have a list of urls in a txt or csv file.

https://superuser.com/users/1277284
https://superuser.com/users/1327728
https://superuser.com/users/3577284
.....

Now I want to open every link in same tab and wait 2-3 seconds between each link. I'm unable to do this with iMacros as my Mac doesn't support it.

Comment: The question is interesting, but why would you want to do that with a list of Stack Exchange accounts, which do not even exist apparently?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. I used Stack Exchange accounts url for example. The actual urls are not to be shared here.